# callback issue when using tf::MessageFilter

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am trying to use Message filter just like given in the tutorial 'Using Stamped datatypes with tf::MessageFilter'. for two messages. tf and odom .  I also have one more subscriber (which is not synchronized) and has its own callback.

Here is what I am doing:

```
tf::TransformListener tf;
tf::MessageFilter<nav_msgs::Odometry> * tf_filter;
message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry> odom_sub;
//initialisation
method1_sub = nh_.subscribe( "topic1",1,&ClassA::method1Callback, this);
odom_sub.subscribe(nh_, "in_odom", 10);
tf_filter = new tf::MessageFilter<nav_msgs::Odometry>(odom_sub, tf,target_frame, 10);
tf_filter->registerCallback( boost::bind(&ClassA::callback_odom, this, _1 ));
//callback
void callback_odom( const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg )
{
ROS_INFO_STREAM("callback_odom Test");
}

void method1Callback( const geometry_msgs::xyz::ConstPtr& msg )
{
 ROS_INFO_STREAM(" method1Callback Test");
}
```

But my callback_odom callback  function is not getting called;However method1Callback does get called. Does anybody know what might be going wrong? What I want to do is process some data in the 'callback_odom' and then use it further.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31505/callback-issue-when-using-tf::messagefilter/) by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-09**:
What are you setting as the target frame?  What is "tf", is it different that "tf_"? Do you get any message outputs from rxconsole?

**Comment by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on 2012-04-10**:
Sorry it was a typing mistake. tf was same as _tf. I have corrected it.  I am setting 'odom' as the target frame. In the rxconsole, I can see 'method1Callback Test' which is the implementation of my method1Callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all I got the issue solved. There was a small mismatch in the 'params' between the source file and the launch file. Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) with karma: 36 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0